# Git - error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, git-remote

I am using ubuntu 11.10 machine. I have installed git of version 1.7.7.1. I am using git-cola to push and pull my code and I was able to commit and push my changes successfully.

Now, I have changed my machine and my new system is with the same above configurations. (Ubuntu 11.10 machine and git version 1.7.7.1).

In the new machine, I have issues on **git push**. I got the following error message when I tried to push my code:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

On internet, I found it may due to any one of the following reason:

- Wrong git user password (In my case, I fee that I am using the correct password to push the code. Because, even now I was successful, when I push workspace code from my old system (with the same password!). But the problem is only from my new system.
- To increase buffer size using the following command:

  git config --system http.postBuffer 52428800

I tried this, but no luck. Even tried to increase my buffer size more than 52428800, but still same error.

Stucked on this issue. Can anyone please suggest me a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the remote URL? (`git remote -v`)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It gives:                                       origin http://my_site_url/git/project_name.git (fetch)
origin http://my_site_url/git/project_name.git (push)

Comment: what's `my_site_url`? github? if not, what is the server?

Comment: Hi, I need to thank you. You have saved my time. Now I was able to push my code successfully. I have made a mistake (BIG MISTAKE) on the server url which you have pointed. By mistake I had a dot (.) in my repository URL at end. So I was not able to push my code. I found that my URL is wrong only through the 'git remote -v' command.  Thank you CharlesB.

Comment: I am new to git repository. So please forgive me if the following questions are two basic. As I said above, by mistake I had a dot in my repository url. If this URL is wrong, how was I allowed to pull or clone my project code. I got error only during push!            can you please say me how? Thank you again..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16998/discussion-between-charlesb-and-kamal)

Comment: Hi, I have run into the same issue. Mine is pushing local changes into a TFS-Git repo none of these issues here fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867076/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-401

Comment: I had the same issue with **SmartGit** application (not with git command line). It looks like that application is using its own authentication which was wrong in my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must have made a mistake in the remote URL, double-check the output with `git remote -v` and fix it with

```
 git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

assuming the remote name is `origin`

Answer (score 9):

For people who using TFS git repositories while on Windows. My Windows password recently changed therefor i had

```
error RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

when doing diffrent things like fetch, push or pull. We using TFS git repo. **I fixed this problem deleting my tfs password from Windows Credential Manager through Control Panel.** https://support.microsoft.com/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager .

Comment: We had the same issue, because in our environment we host our own git server and it uses windows usernames and passwords, but still stores the username and password that was last used in the credential manager, so we had to remove that.

Comment: This doesn't just apply to TFS

Comment: This solved my problem with git for windows. It solves the problem with intelliJ, too because it uses git for windows.

Answer (score 5):

The problem solved right after update to git version 1.8.x

Answer (score 4):

In my case, user permission was the problem. I added myself as a valid user of the repository after which 'Push' worked.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I had the same problem and solved it by removing and re-adding the remote:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin http://host:port/my/repo
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

This assumes that you are on the master branch and your only remote is `origin`.

Comment: `fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported`, you should use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` nowadays

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error, for me it was because I didn't have commit permissions for the repository. The 401 error code is the HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error. Once I got permissions the problem was solved.

Comment: I also realized that this error was security reletad, because it said clearly `HTTP 401`. It turns out I was using the wrong user name and password. After using the right credentials I was able to push my commits to the repository as usual.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but my corporate proxy (silently) fails commits or other uploads to github.com.  All other operations against git.com work correctly, obfuscating the issue.

The only solution was to create patches and email them out of the network.  Kludgey but effective.

Comment: I don't know how this answer would be helpful for anyone.

Comment: This was helpful to me!

Answer (score 1):

My problem -- `error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401` -- was solved by issuing `git repack -a -d` prior to `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url has the correct username and password

```
git remote set-url origin http : //username:password..
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was deleting all ".gitignore" files before committing, because I had a few nested Git roots

Note that I just started fresh with a new repository, so I didn't have to deal with reversing commits

Answer (score 0):

I **reinstalled** git for my windows 10 machine.
And the magic happened !!