# Git Error; RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401

Tags: git, svn, tfs, migration

I am trying to get some subversion code - and history into TFS.

Going via GIT seemed like a quick win and following the steps in the below url:

```
http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/08/how-easy-its-to-migrate-svn-to-tfs-2013-git-repo/
```

I made progress, and imported my test svn repository into a 'local' git instance. However when I try and push it to TFS I get an error.

TFS itself is instructing me on how to 'push an existing repository'

```
git remote add origin
http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/TestDVCS3 git push -u origin --all
```

The local GIT repository is ~3GB

This is the message I get

```
Username for 'http://servername:8080': myusername
Password for 'http://myusername@servername:8080':
Counting objects: 145003, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40421/40421), done.
Writing objects: 100% (145003/145003), 826.47 MiB | 919.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 145003 (delta 98198), reused 135297 (delta 89983)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Things to note here:

1. the size of 826.47 MiB seems a bit low
2. the error code(401) implies there was an access issue.
   However at this point I have authenticated and continued so that seems a bit odd.

Does anyone have any experience here?

Comment: Hi, I have since found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2867441/en-us which seems to basically describe the issue. However this is for IIS 7.. and we are on 8.something. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Update to this: the issue above was for a 502 error - not the 401(.2) I was experiencing so it is not relevant.

Comment: I am getting this same issue as well.  Any more leads?

Comment: the same here, what should we do

Comment: The conclusion I got was the repository was too large (anything more than 1 or 2 hundred MB is apparently). For this and other reasons I gave up with this approach. Sorry guys.

Comment: 200mb is not too large for a Git repo in TFS (we have one that is 1GB+). Have you set the http postBuffer setting in your .gitconfig?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit searching I found this [Git - error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544142/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-401-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-u), however you already tried(according your comment). According to atlassian document(https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Git+Push+Fails+-+fatal%3A+The+remote+end+hung+up+unexpectedly) the reason error you got is size of postBuffer and you need to increase it.

Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```