# GIT push fails 401 fatal - Repository GIT with Git TFS 2017 upd1

Tags: git, tfs

What does the error i receive in communication between GIT WebO (v1.8) and Git TFS2017 upd1 depend on? 
The error message is as follows:

> 401 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

what can I check in addition to `http.PostBuffer` and Origin Url ??? Thank you Gabriele

Comment: How did you use the git push? Could you please share the detail steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proxy server?

> The "Smart HTTP" protocol in Git uses "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in
>   POST requests when it contains packed objects greater than 1MB in
>   size. Some proxy servers, like Nginx, do not support this transfer
>   encoding by default, and the requests will be rejected before they get
>   to Stash. Because of this, the Stash logs will not show any extra
>   information.

Whatever, firstly make sure you have the permission to git push for the repository. Then make sure set the remote URL correctly: `git remote set-url origin <new-url>`

Then try to increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Please refer to below article and following the workaround and solution to fix the issue:
[Git Push Fails - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-282988530.html)

Another similar thread for your reference: [Git - error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544142/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-401-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-u/34188748)