# git push error - fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 the requested URL returned error: 401

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

This has completely stumped me. It only occurs when trying to push individual files > 1MB

I C# program that is running on a remote server. The program creates a process and runs a .bat file in cmd.exe.

The .bat file contains basic git commands, it simply checks out a branch, adds files, commits, then pushes

git checkout QA

git config --global --unset http.postBuffer (added for troubleshooting, doesnt fix issue..)

git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400 (added for troubleshooting, doesnt fix issue..)

git add *config*.txt

git add *.sql

git add *.out

git commit -a -m "Resolve Poll"

git push

I am using Azure Devops to run this program as a build on the remote server and when it goes to do the git push it returns

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
 error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 the requested URL returned error: 401

but when i log into the server myself and run the .bat file by double clicking all the git commands run to success without error, even for pushing files > 1MB

What could this be?

**Things i've tried**

Updated GIT for version 2.25

Increased http.postBuffer size

git pushed with username pass in url

used both 'store' and 'manager' methods of git config --global credential.helper

Comment: This error happens only if the file pushed is larger than 1MB. Sounds just like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426635/git-push-fails-401-fatal-repository-git-with-git-tfs-2017-upd1), as mentioned in the thread, you need to increase the Git buffer size: `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`, check [Git Push Fails](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-282988530.html).

Comment: I have tried this solution and no luck, i listed that exact command above
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

Comment: Sorry that i missed you have tried this. Let me confirm something, this 401 issue only happens when the git push is operated by the .bat file from Azure DevOps and the pushed file is larger than 1MB? The .bat file can be run successfully and the file can be pushed even when it's larger than 1MB when you manuallly click it in the server, the .bat file can also work from Azure DevOps when the pushed file is smaller than 1MB? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk8le.png)?

Comment: Right your understanding is correct, the 401 error only occurs when azure devops service runs the .bat file and the file is > 1 MB
If i go to the server and run the .bat file manually (regardless of file size) it runs the git push command successfully

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 401 error (Unauthorized) means you're missing credentials or the credentials you're using aren't valid.  You'll need to figure out what credentials are needed and provide them, usually with a credential helper.

It may be the case that when you log into the server, your credentials are delegated (say, if you're using Kerberos or NTLM), whereas those credentials are not present when the server is running noninteractively.  You could consider issuing an access token or OAuth token of some sort to the server if you can't use anything else.

Comment: that would make sense though if i wasnt able to push files at all,
but this is only the case for pushing commits with larger files > 1 MB, individual files that are smaller than that get pushed just fine

Comment: The “HTTP 401” output means exactly what I said it means; the RFC will confirm that.  It's possible your Azure Devops server does something different for large files, which you could test by setting `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: I configured my credentials as follows

git config --global credential helper store
(creds are stored as .git-credentials under C:/Users/Username/.git-credentials)

still getting the same 401 error